# doesn't have a default value error with set mutator And update observer does not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, mutators

In saving a model, I have an error thats the slug attribute doesn't have a default value.
I had created a setSlugAttribute mutators but it gived me the error again.

```
//Controller save method inside 
* * *
Task::create($request->all());
* * *

//Task model
public function setSlugAttribute(){
    $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug($this->title, '-');
}
```

How can I fix it? It does fix by using observe(saving), doesn't it? Another idea?

I have created an TaskObserver and I set it in ServiceProvider.

**In the observer, updated(Task $task) and updating(Task $task) methods didn't work !**
But the created method works.

```
//Update method inside:
$array = $request->all(['title', 'description', 'deadline', 'budget','guest_token']);
$task = Task::where('id',$request->id)->update($array);
//I am waiting working of udate observer but it don't

//TaskObserver
public function updating(Task $task)
{
    dd("updating");
}
public function updated(Task $task)
{
    dd("updated");
}
```

Comment: Can you also share the piece of code that generates the error, and the actual error?

Comment: @CanVural can you control it now?

Comment: you are calling `update` on the builder not the model itself, you are doing a direct `UPDATE` query on the database, it does not involve the model so there are no events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by doing the following:

```
//when I assigned it to a variable and then calling update method, it worked
$task = Task::where('id',$request->id)->first();
$update = $task->update($request->all(['title', 'description', 'deadline', 'budget','guest_token']));
```

Answer (score -1):

So every time a `Task` is created or updated you want the `slug` column to be auto-populated from `title` column.

Accessors are not good for this. What you want is observers. For observers you have two choice: closure based or class based. Considering your use case is not too complex, I'd choose closure based observers.

You need two events `creating` and `saving` to handle it when the model is first creating, and when model is updating. So your task model should look like this:

```php
<?php

class Task extends Model
{
    protected static function creating()
    {
        static::creating(function ($task) {
            $task->slug = Str::slug($task->title, '-');
        });

        static::saving(function ($task) {
            $task->slug = Str::slug($task->title, '-');
        });
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: it didn't solve my problem. It is not a suitable answer